# How does map function handle errors?

Tags: python

I have beed playing around the [checkio](https://py.checkio.org) and in one of the tasks I have used the following construction:

```
res = list(map(lambda i: i == l[0], l))
```

For one of the test cases `l` was empty, so `l[0]` should have resulted in an `IndexError`, but for some reason `map` function processed it correctly and the final result was an empty list.

Could someone explain why the execution did not result in `IndexError` ? Is it something to do with how `map` processes the errors ?

Comment: I tried replicating your code doing `res = list(map(lambda i: i = l[0], []))` and got `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?` Your syntax is incorrect.

Comment: On which value do you expect your lambda to be called, if the list `l` is empty? Have a think about what `list(map(lambda x: 1/0, []))` does - or even `list(map('foobar', []))` where the string `'foobar'` is obviously not callable.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Sorry about that, of course there should be `==`

Comment: you can rewrite your function as `[i==l[0] for i in l]`  of course if `l` is empty there will be nothing to iterate, so you will end with an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` does not handle exceptions itself; they will be raised as normal. The reason this code is not throwing an `IndexError` is much less mysterious.

`l[0]` only results in an `IndexError` if that code is actually executed. It's executed once for every element in the list `l`, so if `l` is empty, `l[0]` is never executed at all, and so no `IndexError` is raised.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but does it mean that `map` checks if the list is empty before applying a function to each element ?

Comment: It doesn't need to check; it simply applies the function to each element. Zero elements, zero function applications. It's not a special case.